# reactjs progress bar increase simoltaneously for music by duration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like..

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'


class MusicProgress extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {'progress': 1, 'progress_percent': 1}
}

get_music_progress_percent() {
    const { music } = this.props

    var progress = this.state.progress
    var self = this
    if(!(progress >= music.duration)){
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            progress += 2
            var progress_percent = ((progress / music.duration) * 100).toFixed()
            self.setState({'progress': progress})
            self.setState({'progress_percent': progress_percent})
        }, 2000)
        return this.state.progress_percent

    }
    return this.state.progress_percent


}

get_music_progress() {
    const { music, playing_music } = this.props
    var self = this

    $('#' + music.id).progress({
            percent: self.get_music_progress_percent()
    });
}

render() {
    const { music, playing_music } = this.props

    return (
        <div className="three wide column">
            <div className="ui small progress" id={music.id}>
                <div className="bar"></div>
            </div>
            {this.get_music_progress()}
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default MusicProgress
```

Here I can only get the duration of the music using `music.duration`. I want to make a progress bar now.

My `get_music_progress` function is not working well

It should increase in every 1 or 2 second. When the duration ends it the progress bar should complete..

Need some idea or help..

Thank you